# Cannot active SharePoint Server Publishing - missing another feature

Tags: feature, site

I'm trying to active this part from the site features:

**SharePoint Server Publishing

Create a Web page library as well as supporting libraries to create and publish pages based on page layouts.**

The sites that I have created from scratch I have been able to activate this feature but this site has been created by someone else and here I cannot activate it.The error /info i get is this:

**The feature being activated is a Site scoped feature which has a dependency on a Site Collection scoped feature which has not been activated. Please activate the following feature before trying again: SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa**

I cannot find this feature that the error mentions. Can someone help?

Comment: Did you try to find it at _Site collection settings_, not _Site settings_?

Comment: yes I did. This sites setting list does not have a Site collection feature at all. I don't actually have the Site Collection Administration area at all. I was just wondering could the problem be that when the site was created that they chose some options that leave this collection feature out all together

Answer (score 1):

You should first activate the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature at the site collection level, then on the site level.

See the detailed solution [here](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/205322.aspx).

Comment: I know but the problem is that the whole Site Collection Admistration area is missing. So therefore I have no chance of getting to the site collection feature

Comment: So why is that area missing is probably my actual question?

Comment: That means probably that you have not permission for that (you are not a site collection admin).